# What are interesting functions in 2D that vary visually as compositionality increases?

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus, soft-question

I wanted to create a function that its shape was a function of the depth of the compositionality (on a fixed interval). For example consider some compositional function

$$f(x_1, x_2) = g( g( g( h_1(x_1,x_2) ) ) )$$

ideally, when $g$ is applied more times, I'd like the visual shape of the function to change in a way that is noticeable and distinguishable compared to applying it less times (i.e. the compositionality is the important factor).

I tried the function:

$$ f([x_1,x_2]) =  g_L\circ...\circ g_1( cos( cx_1 x_2  ) ) =  \bigcirc^L _l g_l( cos( cx_1 x_2  ) ) $$

where $g_l(x) = g(x) = k(ax^2+bx_1+c)^p$ (with k=0.5, a=1, b=1.01, c=1.1, p=0.6). When I tried three layers of compositional depth (i.e. L=3,2,1) I got the following three graphs:

[image]

Unfortunately, it seems that its essentially the same graph just sort of re-scaled but it doesn't seem any different in any interesting way. I tried other more complicated function but got similar behaviour in that it looks more complicated but adding more depth to the compositionally didn't seem to change the function in any noticeable way (at least not when inspected visually). Other issues that I've found was that adding more compositionally seemed to explode or vanish some regions of the function. I guess that is changing the function a bit but it seemed like boring properties that in the end (form my observations) essentially just smoothed out the curve.

Of course, from my description I have not thought of a metric to measure this type of difference (or do I require it to solve my problem), but it would be nice to have a function that is sort of recursive/compositional (**in 2D**) that doesn't just rescale the same picture when added with more compositional depth.

Comment: You could try something like $x\sin(1/x)/2$. The closer you get to zero, the jumpier it gets, and you get closer to zero every time you apply it. Haven't tried it though.

Comment: @MattSamuel you mean use $g(x) = xsin(1/x) /2$ as the compositional/recursive function to be used? Or just the initial function $h(x)$?

Comment: Use it as $g$. I was under the impression $h$ wouldn't vary.

Comment: @MattSamuel yes, I expect to have $h$ fixed (unless someone has a good suggestion to change it). I did try your suggestion. It does have **very** nice property that the function shape changes as g is applied more but it seems to be a bit violent (in that the jumps get really crazy). I guess I didn't really say, but it would be nice to have it just a bit more moderate. I will see if I can play with its parameters to have the jumps a bit more controlled. Ideally, it would also be nice if it were just a tiny bit less extreme as g is applied more (thought its the best i have right now).

Comment: You could try $x\sin(x^{-0.1})/2$ or $x\sin(\ln x)/2$. That might temper the craziness a bit. The function inside the parentheses should go to infinity as $x$ goes to zero, but it can do it as slowly as you want.

Comment: You may want to shy $|x|^{-0.1}$ or $\ln |x|$ though since these numbers can certainly be negative.

Comment: @MattSamuel nice! That produces graphs that are much better. Though, around the corners (of the interval) the graph is really really really jumpy. I'm trying to adjust the power of $|x|^p$ so that there are some jumps and also the period of $h(x) = cos(cx_1x_2)$ but I'm having a hard time deciding which one to change so that we have sort of a few humps of the sine but also enough variability when depth increases. Those two are the parameters to change if I want to control those to properties, right? (also if you find a cool setting feel free to share them! thnx for the help! :D)

Comment: Yeah. Also the factor of $1/2$ may be making it harder to control. I put it in there to ensure that it got smaller every time, but even without that factor it gets smaller almost everywhere, just not at values of $2/(n\pi)$ for integers $n$. Dividing by $2$ could be too drastic. Changing that factor should have a similar effect to making the function inside the parentheses slower.

Comment: @MattSamuel It seems that there two main forces that determine the shape of the function. Consider $$axsin(bln(x))$$ where $x = cos(kx_1x_2^2)$. If the arguments to (any) function increase, then the function gets squeezed. In this case increasing b squeezes the function. Also, if we have small $a$ then the function gets jumpier and jumpier. If you ever get to produce an answer it would be nice to discuss these details. I think they are (sort of) right?

Comment: @MattSamuel I've seen empirically that your suggested function works but I still not quite appreciate why increasingly composing that functions works the way I wanted. (thanks for the help so far though! :D )

Comment: My intuition was that there's no limit to how crazy $\sin(1/x)$ gets as you approach $0$, so if you push the function closer to zero and keep plugging it back in it should get crazier and crazier, so you would need something that both makes it smaller and applies $\sin(1/x)$. I haven't checked this with a computer and I don't have one handy but what you are saying seems reasonable.